# logically Understanding a compression algorithm

Tags: arrays, algorithm, io

this idea had been flowing in my head for 3 years and i am having problems to apply it
i wanted to create a compression algorithm that cuts the file size in half

e.g. 8 mb to 4 mb

and with some searching and experience in programming i understood the following.
let's take a .txt file with letters (a,b,c,d)

using the `IO.File.ReadAllBytes` function , it gives the following array of bytes : ( 97 | 98 | 99 | 100 ) , which according to this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart is the decimal value of the letter.

what i thought about was : how to mathematically cut this 4-membered-array to only 2-membered-array by combining each 2 members into a single member but you can't simply mathematically combine two numbers and simply reverse them back as you have many possibilities,e.g.
80 | 90 : 90+80=170 but there is no way to know that 170 was the result of 80+90 not like 100+70 or 110+60.
and even if you could overcome that , you would be limited by the maximum value of bytes (255 bytes) in a single member of the array.

i understand that most of the compression algorithms use the binary compression and they were successful,but imagine cutting a file size in half , i would like to hear your ideas on this.

Best Regards.

Comment: Take a look at [Huffman Coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding).  The basic gist of compression is that you _replace_ the combination `80 | 90` with a some sort of placeholder.  When decoding, you lookup the placeholder in a table and obtain the original bytes.

Comment: i know about huffman but it can't reach my goal (half size compression) i need a more simple way to combine numbers within 0~255 range

Comment: Can you let us know how many combinations `A | B` bytes appear in your data set?

Comment: there isn't actually a data set , it's just an examble, i just have an array of  97 | 98 | 99 | 100 which is originally abcd

Comment: what do you mean with "cuts the file size in half"? what kind of file (if you allow any file, you could compress the result again and again and end up with a 0 byte file - which is unrealistic). you can only compress a file if the information contained in the file is less than the disk space taken by the file (expressed as the "enthropy" in Huffman coding). So you can only compress a file to 50% its original size if it really takes double the space necessary.

Comment: i think you are right , i was looking at it the wrong angle , if i have a way to compress (x) and (y) to (z) and (z) with another number (f) then we would reach to a point where we have only (S) byte which should tell us the whole contents of a 50 gb file. not realistic at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to make a compression algorithm that makes every file shorter.  The proof is called the "counting argument", and it's easy:

There are 256^L possible files of length L.

Lets say there are N(L) possible files with length < L.

If you do the math, you find that 256^L = 255*N(L)+1

So.  You obviously cannot compress every file of length L, because there just aren't enough shorter files to hold them uniquely.  If you made a compressor that always shortened a file of length L, then MANY files would have to compress to the same shorter file, and of course you could only get one of them back on decompression.

In fact, there are more than 255 times as many files of length L as there are shorter files, so you can't even compress *most* files of length L.  *Only a small proportion can actually get shorter*.

This is explained pretty well (again) in the comp.compression FAQ:
http://www.faqs.org/faqs/compression-faq/part1/section-8.html

EDIT:  So maybe you're now wondering what this compression stuff is all about...

Well, the vast majority of those "all possible files of length L" are random garbage.  Lossless data compression works by assigning shorter representations (the output files) to the files we *actually use*.

For example, Huffman encoding works character by character and uses fewer bits to write the most common characters.  "e" occurs in text more often than "q", for example, so it might spend only 3 bits to write "e"s, but 7 bits to write "q"s.  bytes that hardly ever occur, like character 131 may be written with 9 or 10 bits -- longer than the 8-bit bytes they came from.  On average you can compress simple English text by almost half this way.

LZ and similar compressors (like PKZIP, etc) remember all the strings that occur in the file, and assign shorter encodings to strings that have already occurred, and longer encodings to strings that have not yet been seen.  This works even better since it takes into account more information about the context of every character encoded.  On average, it will take fewer bits to write "boy" than "boe", because "boy" occurs more often, even though "e" is more common than "y".

Since it's all about predicting the characteristics of the files you actually use, it's a bit of a black art, and different kinds of compressors work better or worse on different kinds of data -- that's why there are so many different algorithms.